# Best practice stock management when payment of customer failed using SQL Server and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2008

I am currently building a webshop for my own where I want to increment the product-stock when the user fails to complete payment within 10 minutes after the customer placed the order. I want to gather information from this thread to make a design decision.

I am using SQL Server 2008 and ASP.NET 3.5. Should I use a SQL Server Job who intervals check the orders which are not payed yet or are there better solutions to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Martijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I would work with a scheduled job. Run it every minute.

If the application is larger, a triggered application may also work (an exe that you start from the job scheduler in asp.net). Depends on the logic - I would not put more into the stored procedure than I have to in business logic, if you do stuff there that is more complicated - i would not put it into SQL.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger a scheduled job and run it for the time there are active unpaid orders (order which are not payed but still in the 10 minute time window)

Comment: No, and it makes little sense. The trigger condition would be too complicated. What you can do is trigger a job every minute that first checks what orders are unpaid for 10 minutes and then processes those - and then falls asleep again.

Comment: Was looking at my old questions and saw that I forgot to vote this as a answer. The final solution involved a windows service which does the background processing.